# Use dynamic linq filters in the Include and ThenInclude part of a entity framework core query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

**What i want to achieve:**

Currently I'm working on a filter system which will based on user input apply different filters on entites. That is an easy task if you just focus on the root entity or on Many-to-one relationships. But as soon as you want to filter on collections it gets a little bit harder to express and also harder to query.

**The Problem:**

I want to filter on the root entity (Organization) and also want to filter on collections like Organization.Contracts or Contract.Licenses. I have the option to add a selection to the **Include** and **ThenInclude** clause (see my example). But i can only add fixed LINQ-Querys but not build dynamic functions to select the right rows.

**The Exception:**

```
System.ArgumentException: "Expression of type 'System.Func`2[ExpressionTreeTest.MinimalTest+Contract,System.Boolean]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[ExpressionTreeTest.MinimalTest+Contract,System.Boolean]]' of method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[ExpressionTreeTest.MinimalTest+Contract] Where[Contract](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[ExpressionTreeTest.MinimalTest+Contract], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[ExpressionTreeTest.MinimalTest+Contract,System.Boolean]])' Arg_ParamName_Name"
```

Based on the exception i saw, that Entity Framework Core wants a **System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[ExpressionTreeTest.MinimalTest+Contract,System.Boolean]]** but i provide a **System.Func`2[ExpressionTreeTest.MinimalTest+Contract,System.Boolean]**. As soon as i change this to **Expression<Func<Contract, bool>> ContractFilterExpression = c => c.EndDate > DateTime.Now.AddMonths(11);** intellisense reports an error, that this can not be accepted.

**Other awnsers:**

I found many different questions about querying entity framework core and building dynamic queries. Based on this I was able to build my dynamic queries for the root entity (Organization). But for the nested ThenInclude list queries i could not find any dynamic example.

**My minimal test case for you:**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace ExpressionTreeTest
{

public class MinimalTest
{

    public void RunTest()
    {
        AppDbContext dbContext = new AppDbContext();
        dbContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
        dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();

        // Setup some test data to check the query results
        SetupTestData(dbContext);

        // Pre build query with entity framework, which is working as expected
        // Expectation:
        // Get all Organizations with the Name == NameOfCompany and
        // Include all Organization.Contracts which are Created > ateTime.Now.AddMonths(12)
        // ThenInclude all Contract.Licenses which are l.Articel.Name == "TestArticelName"
        IQueryable<Organization> preBuildQuery = dbContext.Organizations.Where(o => o.Name == "NameOfCompany").
            Include(c => c.Contracts.Where(c => c.Created > DateTime.Now.AddMonths(12))).
            ThenInclude(l => l.Licenses.Where(l => l.Articel.Name == "TestArticelName"));

        // This prints 1, which is the desired result
        Console.WriteLine("Query result count: " + preBuildQuery.ToList().Count());

        // This is the dynamic filter funtion for the Include-Part of the query
        // This function gets accepted by Visual Studio but throws an error by Entity Framework
        Func<Contract, bool> ContractFilterFunction = c => c.EndDate > DateTime.Now.AddMonths(11);

        // Build the above query dynamically based on user input
        IQueryable<Organization> dynamicQuery = dbContext.Organizations.Where(BuildWhereQuery()).
            Include(c => c.Contracts.Where(ContractFilterFunction)).
            ThenInclude(l => l.Licenses.Where(l => l.Articel.Name == "TestArticelName"));

        // This is the line with the error you will find in the question
        // If i remove the ContractFilterFunction and replace it with an inline lambda
        // the query gets executed, but i am not able to dynamically set the query parameters.
        Console.WriteLine("Query result count: " + dynamicQuery.ToList().Count());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method creates based on input a query with different types. In the future there
    /// should be some select based on the binaryExpression to use (Equal, Greater, etc.)
    /// At the moment this is static for testing purposes
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A Func<T,bool> to parse to a Linq-Entity-Framewor query</returns>
    private Expression<Func<Organization, bool>> BuildWhereQuery()
    {
        ParameterExpression rootEntity = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Organization));
        MemberExpression fieldExpression = Expression.PropertyOrField(rootEntity, "Name");
        ConstantExpression valueToCompare = Expression.Constant("NameOfCompany");
        var binaryExpression = Expression.Equal(fieldExpression, valueToCompare);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<Organization, bool>>(binaryExpression, rootEntity);
    }

    public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Organization> Organizations { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }

        public DbSet<License> Licenses { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Articel> Articels { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(@"Data Source=mydb.db");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
        }
    }

    public class BasicEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

    }

    public class Organization : BasicEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }

        public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }

    }

    public class Articel : BasicEntity
    {

        public string Name { get; set; }

    }

    public class Contact : BasicEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Organization Organization { get; set; }
    }

    public class Contract : BasicEntity
    {

        public DateTime Created { get; set; }

        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

        public List<License> Licenses { get; set; }

        public Organization Organization { get; set; }

    }

    public class License : BasicEntity
    {

        public string LicenseNumber { get; set; }

        public Articel Articel { get; set; }

        public Contract Contract { get; set; }

    }

    private static void SetupTestData(AppDbContext dbContext)
    {
        Organization org = new Organization
        {
            Name = "NameOfCompany",
        };
        dbContext.Add(org);
        dbContext.Add(new Contact
        {
            Name = "Contact 1",
            Organization = org
        });
        dbContext.Add(new Contact
        {

            Name = "Contact 2",
            Organization = org
        });
        Articel articel = new Articel
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Name = "TestArticelName"
        };
        dbContext.Add(articel);
        Contract contract = new Contract
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Created = DateTime.Now,
            EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(12),
            Organization = org
        };
        dbContext.Add(contract);
        License license = new License
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            LicenseNumber = "12345-12345",
            Articel = articel,
            Contract = contract
        };
        dbContext.Add(license);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
}
```

**Note:**

If you have any additional tips for me or even a workaround or other solution, I would be very happy. It's not a requirement to do it like this, but it's the only way I found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way to solve your issue is to install [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) - `LinqKit.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`

Add `WithExpressionExpanding` in `OnConfiguring`

```cs
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(@"Data Source=mydb.db");
    optionsBuilder.WithExpressionExpanding();
}
```

Make dynamic filter function as a `Expression`, EF Core will not translate `Func<>` to the SQL and use LINQKit extension `Invoke`:

```cs
// This is the dynamic filter function for the Include-Part of the query
Expression<Func<Contract, bool>> ContractFilterFunction = c => c.EndDate > DateTime.Now.AddMonths(11);

IQueryable<Organization> dynamicQuery = dbContext.Organizations.Where(BuildWhereQuery())
    .Include(c => c.Contracts.Where(c => ContractFilterFunction.Invoke(c)))
    .ThenInclude(l => l.Licenses.Where(l => l.Articel.Name == "TestArticelName"));
```

`LINQKit` extension will expand `LambdaExpression` `ContractFilterFunction` and inject into final Expression Tree before processing by EF Core's LINQ Translator.

Comment: Thank you! This was really helpfull. I tried to understand, why its working now and what LinqKit does, but thats a littel to magic for me. I think i need to dive deeper into LinqToSql, Linq and Entity Framework Core.