# Entity Framework - Trying to call expression to work out percentage

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expression-trees

In Entity Framework 6 i am trying to call an expression that will work out the percentage (10%) of a Decimal and give that back.

I have done

```
Expression<Func<int, int>> ExpiringValue = Value => (int)(10 / 100 * Value);
Func<int, int> ExpiringValueFn = ExpiringValue.Compile();
```

just above the query as a test and then am calling it by

```
from foo in context.stuff
select new {
 Moo = SqlFunctions.DateAdd("Month", ExpiringValueFn((int)foo.MonthsValidFor), SqlFunctions.CurrentTimestamp())
}
```

But I am getting the error "The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities." I was working from this (https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-expression)

Any ideas?

Comment: Answered several times almost the same question: [yesterday's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74364583/10646316). You cannot pass `Func<>` and expect that EF Core will translate query. With EF 6, use LINQKit's `AsExpandable()` since `WithExpressionExpanding` is implemented only for EF Core.

Comment: Your code has syntax errors. Please put in valid code.

Answer (score 0):

The following is just an idea, not yet tested on my side.

In order to incorporate a predefined function expression into your select, split it into a chain of selects that separately process input, function expression and output. This way you can avoid manual manipulation of the expression tree.

```
Expression<Func<int, int>> valueFn = Value => (int)(0.1 * Value);

var result = context.stuff
    .Select(x => (int)x.MonthsValidFor)
    .Select(valueFn)
    .Select(x => new {
        Moo = SqlFunctions.DateAdd("Month", x, SqlFunctions.CurrentTimestamp())
    });
```